# List View With ObservableCollection Not Updating While Adding Or Deleting Records

Tags: c#, listview, observablecollection, updating

My ListView is not updating itself while adding or deleting items. Moreover, When I close and re-open the form, updated list comes up. Here is the c# code:

```
using Library;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

namespace Bajaj.ViewModels
{
    #region Records...
    public class _REC_LedgerGroup
    {
        public int sno { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string alias { get; set; }

        public _REC_LedgerGroup(int sno, int id, string name, string alias)
        {
            this.sno = sno;
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.alias = alias;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    public class GroupListVM : ObservableCollection<_REC_LedgerGroup>
    {
        public GroupListVM()
            : base()
        {
            CollectionChanged += GroupListVM_CollectionChanged;

            Database DB = new Database();
            DB.Open();
            try
            {
                MySqlCommand command = DB.connection.CreateCommand();
                command.CommandText = "select * from ledgergroups order by id;";
                MySqlDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteReader();
                if (rdr.HasRows)
                {
                    List<_REC_LedgerGroup> RC = new List<_REC_LedgerGroup>();
                    int count = 0;
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        count++;
                        Add(
                            new _REC_LedgerGroup(
                                count,
                                Convert.ToInt32(rdr["id"]),
                                rdr["name"].ToString(),
                                rdr["alias"].ToString()
                                ));
                    }

                    rdr.Close();
                    DB.Close();
                }
                else { DB.Close(); }
            }
            catch { DB.Close(); }
        }

        private void GroupListVM_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the XAML:

```
<ListView 
            x:Name="GroupList" 
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="5" 
            Background="#FFEEEEEE" Margin="0,2" FontSize="12" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupListCollection}}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Sno" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding sno}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="ID" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding id}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding name}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Alias" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding alias}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

I don't know where I am getting wrong.

Comment: You have two issues for what we can see 1) You are not setting the datacontext anywhere we can see and 2) You must notify the property system of an update using either INPC or a DP.

Comment: Thanks a lot John. It worked with Dependency Property.